# random function in Java

Tags: java, random

I want to know how to get a 4-digit random number in Java. I was trying to do it and everytime I run the program I always get the same number.
Thanks

Comment: What's your code? Most probably you are using the same seed every time.

Comment: It's hard to know what you've done wrong without seeing your code. Also, are you looking for a number between 1000 and 9999, or would 5 (equal to 0005) be okay?

Comment: Please show the code then we can trace what went wrong

Comment: Always post your code so you know what you did wrong.

Comment: I already found out how to do it thanks anyway. But please now I need to do same random but with a 16-digit number. And the random function I got doesn't work with big numbers. I got this function:

int pin = new Random().nextInt(10000);

But if I put a big number like 1000000000000, it won't work because it's not int, and the nextLong is not working to me like that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
int randomNumber = ( int )( Math.random() * 9999 );

if( randomNumber <= 1000 ) {
    randomNumber = randomNumber + 1000;
```

Math.random() is a method that generates a random number through a formula. It returns a double however, so casting is required if you want an integer, float, or etc. The if block makes sure that the number is above 1000 and is a 4-digit number.

Comment: This is a bad solution. Ten percent of the values obtained in the first line will fall between 1000 and 2000. Another ten percent will fall below 1000 and your `if` block will increment them and then you will have 20 percent of the results between 1000 and 2000.

Comment: @madth3 it is not my preferred solution, but random does not imply uniform - so it still qualifies.

Comment: @madth3 what do you provide for this solution? cuz what you're saying is right and I won't get a number between 0 and 999, how can i get a number between 0 and 999 adding zeros at the beggining like 0033?

Comment: @Johnny: Just use `new Random().nextInt(10000)`. The leading zeroes are an output issue, this has nothing to do with the problem of creating the number. You could use `System.out.printf("%04d\n", number)`, for example.

Comment: @NiklasB. But I have to do an atm software and it has to generate a 4-digit number pin and it has to be shown to the user, so i need the 4 digits including the leading zeroes.

Comment: @Johnny: Is this homework or are you actually developing ATM software? LOL if the latter is the case. In the former case, please mark it as such next time using the [homework] tag. In any case, my comment contained the solution, please re-read it

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes, is homework but I forgot to put the tag, let me see if it works, Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) class:

```
int randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(9000) + 1000;
```

Comment: 8999+1000, or you can get 10000 which 5 digits

Answer (score 1):

Working solution - different number each time

```
Random r = new Random();
int fourDigit = 1000 + r.nextInt(10000);
System.out.println(fourDigit);
```

Broken - same number every time

```
Random r = new Random(123);  // <---- uses same seed every time !
int fourDigit = 1000 + r.nextInt(9000);
System.out.println(fourDigit);
```